# "I had chicken for dinner" vs "I ate chicken for dinner"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

> 1. I **had** chicken for dinner.
> 2. I **ate** chicken for dinner.

Is there any difference? Could anyone tell me the difference? Probably state vs action?

Which one is more colloquial?

Comment: They are equivalent, though the first form can more easily be associated with comedic abuse of the language.

Comment: To me- "I had chicken for dinner" allows that this was a full dinner with side dishes etc. while "I ate chicken for dinner" is more likely to mean that the only thing you ate for dinner was chicken.

Answer (score 1):

"I had chicken for dinner" is the more common usage by a substantial margin, in my experience.

"I ate chicken for dinner" is more literal - technically correct, but it feels more stilted.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but *have* is perhaps a bit more discreet by comparison. To me, *eat* is more direct and makes you think of chewing, swallowing, etc.

Frequency-wise, *have* wins hands-down:

[image]

Also, what works with chicken doesn't work with cake: you can't [have your cake and eat it too](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+cake+and+eat+it+too)! :)

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic expression is **have...for dinner** (or any meal or meal part, such as an appetizer, main dish or dessert).  You could say:

**I was hungry after lunch, so I ate a piece of chicken.**

You could also say:

**I was hungry after lunch, so I had a piece of chicken.**

But once you introduce **for dinner**, it sounds unnatural (non-native) to use **ate**.

- **What did you have** (not **eat**) **for dinner?**
- **I had chicken/chicken with rice/chicken, peas and mashed potatoes.**

Is there a specific reason? I doubt it; it's just what we way, and it's a "tell" between native and non-native English.